# script cannot detect chinese characters in the file after cx_freeze

Tags: python, regex, utf-8, io, utf8-decode

I have 2 different issues but they are closely related with each other:

1) my python script copies the original code file to another file and read it line by line (utf-8) , detect chinese characters with regex and sends them to google translate , gets the answer back, write another file with the translation after the line containing chinese characters. This works perfectly under pycharm when i directly run the script under windows. However after converting into executable with cx_freeze, it basically reads the file but cannot see any chinese chars , so no translation is being done.Can you please help ?

2) executable works on some other computers(windows).I found out that it has a strong relation with the windows -system locale settings`. After setting it to chinese we can make it work. I tried to change it via script by locale module with no success.

Here is the code snippets that might help to understand the problem:

```
def initialize(self):
    #several imports here
    #several filename operations here

    writefileF = codecs.open(writefile, "w", "utf-8")

    # copy the original to another with  utf-8 encoding (to be safe)
    with io.open(self.orig_filename, ) as source:
            with io.open(readFileN, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as target:
                try:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)
                except:
                    print 'trying single copy file with no metadata.. '
                    shutil.copyfile(self.filename, readFileN)
   readFile = codecs.open(readFileN, "r", "utf-8")
   # generAtor func call
   creategen = self.readfilebylines(readFile)
   for iterator in creategen:
       endd = myconcat.join(iterator[0])
       writefileF.writelines(myconcat.join(endd))

def readfilebylines(self, myfileobj):
    linenum = 0
    for lines in myfileobj.readlines():            
        mygen = lines
        mymatch = self.regularexpmatch(lines)
        if mymatch:
            print 'chinese word detected'
            #do translation
        else:
            pass
        yield mygen, linenum

def regularexpmatch(self, mytext):
    chinese_compile = re.compile(ur'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+')
    matched = chinese_compile.search(mytext)
    return matched
```

Answer (score 0):

I`ve struggled for hours and finally found a solution. The problem is script somehow could not change encoding of files if you do not specify the original file encoding.

So for my case:

```
def copyfile_inUTF8(self,orig_file,copy_file):
    import chardet
    raw_data=open(orig_file,'r').read()
    target_en='utf-8'
    #detect sourcefile encoding
    orig_en=chardet.detect(raw_data)['encoding']
    print 'original file encoding:',orig_en
    target = open(copy_file, "w")
    target.write(unicode(raw_data, orig_en).encode(target_en))
    print 'copy file encoding:',chardet.detect(open(copy_file,'r').read())['encoding']
```

Using that function i was able to see the original encoding and change it to target encoding which is utf-8.